# How can I resolve this validation error about div element?

Tags: html, parent-child

I'm new to coding so there are still a lot of terms and things that I do not understand. I was checking my code through a validator and got this error, could someone please explain what it means and how to fix it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Personal Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/012219d900.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
.text-box{
background-color: transparent;
color: #FFF;
margin: 20px;
padding: 20px;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="sub-header">
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html">AMANDA YEE</a>
                <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
                  <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">GALLERY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">CV</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
            </nav>
            <h1>MY STORY</h1>
</section>

<!--experience content-->
<section class="CV">

<div class="timeline">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="content">
            <h3>Right now...
            </h3>
            <h4>@Pratt Institute<br>New York City, NY, United States
            </h4>
            <p>M.S. Interaction Experience Design
            </p>
            </div>
            <div class="time">
                <p>Aug 2021 - present
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content">
            <h3>Autopilot Data Analyst
            </h3>
            <h4>@Tesla<br>San Mateo, CA, United States
            </h4>
            <p>Utilized the Autopilot labeling interface to train Tesla's deep neural network using image recognition and classification to achieve Full Self Driving.
            </p>
            </div>
            <div class="time">
                <p>Jan 2021 - Aug 2021
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content">
            <h3>Graduated!
            </h3>
            <h4>@UC Davis<br>Davis, CA, United States
            </h4>
            <p>B.A. Communications<br>B.A. Japanese
            </p>
            </div>
            <div class="time">
                <p>Sep 2017 - Dec 2020
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content">
            <h3>Study Abroad in Japan
            </h3>
            <h4>@Keio University<br>Tokyo, Japan
            </h4>
            <p>Concentration in International Business & Intercultural Communication
            </p>
            </div>
            <div class="time">
                <p>Sep 2019 - Apr 2020
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content">
            <h3>Administrative Assistant &<br>English Second Language Teacher
            </h3>
            <h4>@LeafCup English Cafe and School<br>Tokyo, Japan
            </h4>
            <p> Checked-in customers, handled payroll activities, conducted language proficiency tests, and advertised events and promotions across various social media platforms.<br><br>Facilitated small group discussions with university students, businesspersons, retirees, etc. to develop basic speaking/listening English skills.
            </p>
            </div>
            <div class="time">
                <p>Dec 2019 - Apr 2020
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content">
            <h3>Content Curator
            </h3>
            <h4>@TOKI<br>Tokyo, Japan
            </h4>
            <p>Researched, edited, and built content for the Itinerary Builder database and translated text projects and website content from Japanese to English.
            </p>
            </div>
            <div class="time">
                <p>Nov 2019 - Dec 2019
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        
        <li>
            <div class="content">
            <h3>Advertising & Web Graphic Designer
            </h3>
            <h4>@TOKI<br>Tokyo, Japan
            </h4>
            <p>Drafted UXUI designs for an optimized module for itinerary and curation proposals and led content curation procedures.<br><br>Coordinated with department managers and engineering team to plan marketing campaign timelines and internal materials.
            </p>
            </div>
            <div class="time">
                <p>June 2019 - Aug 2019
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content">
            <h3>Advertising & Design Student Assistant
            </h3>
            <h4>@UC Davis, East Asian Studies Dept.<br>Davis, CA, United States
            </h4>
            <p>Designed e-newsletters, flyers, brochures, etc. and maintained the UC Davis East Asian Studies Department website.
            </p>
            </div>
            <div class="time">
                <p>Apr 2018 - June 2019
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="content">
            <h3>Teaching Assistant
            </h3>
            <h4>@UC Davis, East Asian Studies Dept.<br>Davis, CA, United States
            </h4>
            <p>Facilitated weekly seminars alongside program lecturers and coordinated course logistics and student communications.
            </p>
            </div>
            <div class="time">
                <p>Apr 2018 - June 2019
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <div style="clear: both;">
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>

</section>



<!--Footer-->

<section class="footer">
    <div class="icons">
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
    </div>
</section>






<!--Javascript for Toggle Menu-->
    <script>
        var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");
        
        function showMenu(){
            navLinks.style.right = "0";
        }
        function hideMenu(){
            navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
        }
    </script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Element div not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

From line 173, column 3; to line 173, column 28

```
    </li>↩      <div style="clear: both;">↩     </d
```

Contexts in which element div may be used:
Where flow content is expected.
As a child of a dl element.
Content model for element ul:
Zero or more li and script-supporting elements.

Comment: Note that the `<meta>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

I do think the answer might be your Clearfix (Clear:both) at the end of CV section. The clearfix is inside the list (UL), try moving that enter Div down by 1 line below the closign of the list (/ul).